# How to make an npyscreen widget that only accepts numbers

Tags: python, user-interface, tui, npyscreen

I am using the latest version of npyscreen.

I want to make a Text widget that only supports numbers, it should do nothing when any other character is inserted, not display it or save it.

Preferably, I want it to display it in a set format like `xx.xxxx`.

I have tried overriding Text widgets like TitleText, but I have found no way to achieve what I want.